# OpenModelicaText getting commented when adding Bitmaps in Icon/Diagram View

Tags: openmodelica

I've noticed that the OM Script gets commented when I add a bitmap in either the Icon/Diagram View.

I'm using OpenModelica 1.9.1+dev (r18667) (RML version)

Code for reference

```
model Test
  annotation(Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100,-100},{100,100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2,2}), graphics = {Bitmap(origin = {0.12,-0.47}, extent = {{-99.77,99.65000000000001},{99.77,-99.65000000000001}}, fileName = "modelica://Test/C:/Users/MSK/Desktop/Capture.PNG")}));
end Test;
```

[image]

This may be a bug. Hence I've reported it

Comment: I may have found why this happens. the // after modelica: seems to be commenting out the rest of the line rendering the " after Capture.PNG invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenModelica bug reports should be reported at: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket

And yes, it is a bug so it does not really belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have reported it on the Bug Tracker

Comment: The bug is fixed in r20995.